# Ad hoc app unable to install on iPhone 6 but installing on all other devices

Tags: ios, ios8, installation, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-6

I have an app which is working fine on simulator for iPhone 6 or 6+ but when ad hoc build is being installed, it get stuck and all I see a gray icon saying "installing". I have added all UDID's correctly and provisioning profile is absolutely fine. So can anybody help what else might be missing? I am using following settings for architecture. Thanks !

[image: Architectures set in the projetct]

and error on iPhone 6 device after installation is:
[image]

Comment: It may happen because of supported architecture not there in the build.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? @cyberlobe

Comment: Plug the phone into your mac, bring up Devices and check the logs.  That will generally help to narrow down the issue.  I would guess it is something wrong with your provisioning file.

Comment: @MikeM in provisioning profile, like what? I have double checked my UDIDs, provisioning profile has been recreated and its working on other devices  absolutely fine.

Comment: @Rana, ah ok, if it's working on other hardware devices, then you're right, the provisioning file is prob okay.  Again, though, the log for the iPhone 6 should tell you what is failing.